# Ckan Extension installation

Tags: ckan

### CKAN Version

2.6.2

### Problem

Im trying to install an extension, to be specific

https://github.com/EUDAT-B2FIND/ckanext-b2find

https://github.com/EUDAT-B2FIND/ckanext-datesearch

### Please describe the actual behaviour

Cant see the extension in Ckan, but the extension seem's to be enable because ckan is up and running, yet there's are no error in /var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log

### What steps can be taken to reproduce the issue?

In the extension folder i did python setup.py install
in /etc/ckan/default/production.ini added b2find and datesearch in line ckan.plugins
restarted apache2

### Other information

Ubuntu 14.04
Apache2

Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this?

Best Regards Gonçalo

Answer (score 1):

Some checks to try, which generally apply to all ckan extensions:

- The normal one is `python setup.py develop` because that copies more files, depending on the extension's configuration. Try that instead of `python setup.py install`. No harm in trying.
- Did you enable the virtualenv when you did `python setup.py install`? Enable the virtualenv and try `python -c 'import ckanext.b2find'`.
- Are you editing the same .ini as is being used by apache? Try commenting out `sqlalchemy.url` temporarily and check restarting apache2 fails.
- You haven't got two lines in your .ini with `ckan.plugins` in, have you? If that happens, one gets ignored.
- Are you sure the extension is not working? Some aren't visible unless you are logged in or on a particular page or something. I'm not familiar with these two.
- Have you customized any templates? If you don't have the Jinja blocks all there still, then the extension may have problems hooking into it.

Comment: First i would like to thanks for your fast reply.
I have done
 
python setup.py develop
python -c 'import ckanext.b2find

And the he gave me an error saying that he cant find the plugin.
Im already logged in
Only have one line (ckan.plugin)
How do i know if apache is using my production.ini and how can i force apache to use the one i want?

Comment: Dont know if this helps _Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module._

Comment: Ok sounds like you found the nub of the problem, if you are running 'python setup.py develop' to install this python module, yet you can't then import it in python. I can't help you debug this in any more detail.